# Istio: conditional-rate-limits based on Url

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, rate-limiting, istio

I would like to update the conditional-rate-limit to be based on a match of the URL in the request.

I found these docs, https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/istio.policy.v1beta1/#Rule

But can't track down what the correct attribute would be to use

---

As a guess, I tried

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  match: match(request.uri, "/A/B/93*") == true
  actions:
  - handler: handler.memquota
    instances:
    - requestcount.quota
```

But that errors with

```
Unable to compile match condition expression: 'unknown attribute request.uri', rule='quota.rule.istio-system',
enter code here
```

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### From Martin on the Istio Google Group!

I think if you change from request.uri to request.path, things should start working for you.

Here's the set of supported attributes: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/attribute-vocabulary/

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Rate limit configuration is split into two parts.

Client Side
Mixer Side

Run the following command to enable rate limits using memquota:

$ kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/policy/mixer-rule-productpage-ratelimit.yaml

See the attached link[1] for enabling Rate Limits.

[1]https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/

Comment: [1] link is broken